# Return data from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, return

I have a Python script that prints and returns all image files from a folder in the server.

```
import os
images = ""
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('..\directory'):
    for filename in filenames:
        images = images + os.path.join(dirname, filename) + "^"
print(images)
return images
```

I am calling this in Javascript using:

```
$.get("scripts/filename.py", function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

However, instead of the getting the 'printed' or returned data, it is just displaying the code from filename.py. Am I missing something here?

EDIT:
By the way, I am using Google App Engine to host my website.

Comment: what framework are you using? just only the python cannot help you with what you are doing now, you should run the development server with some framework, e.g. django framework, easy and powerful one.

Comment: @doniyor I am using google app engine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have some Web Framework setup like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/). I would suggest go with Flask, it's the easiest Web Framework to get started with.

And then you need to have some endpoint to which you can send an `AJAX GET` Request, and then your Python script will return a JSON response. You can iterate through this JSON response to print out the results.

This code might work out for you:

```
import sys, os
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, render_template

@app.route('/images')
def index():
    images = ""
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('..\directory'):
        for filename in filenames:
            images = images + os.path.join(dirname, filename) + "^"
    print(images)
    # return a json encoded response
    return Response(json.dumps(images, sort_keys=True, indent=4), mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Now you need to start the server, and whenever you send a GET Request at `localhost:5000/images` it will return the JSON response you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Python set up to run on your server?

- [Configuring the Apache Web Server to Run Python on Windows](http://www.editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html) or
- [How to Configure Apache to run Python on Windows](http://ujjaini.wordpress.com/2010/08/13/how-to-run-python-script-on-apache-on-windows/)

Comment: about that, I am using google app engine to host my application. Right now, I have Google App Engine launcher started, so I access my web page through http://localhost:8080/index.html. I'm not sure if I should still setup python for windows?

Comment: of course you should setup python for windows once you are running your development server if any...

Comment: I did not see any instruction from Google App Engine tutorial about setting up the development server. I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Phyton script in cgi folder